# R - multiple plots from same data-set: same x-value but changing y-value

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-visualization

Very often I have a dataset from which I need to make multiple graphs where the x-value stays the same but the y-value changes.
For example, the df code below has 1 factor variable, year, and 3 measures.
I need to make 3 plots where the only thing that's changing is the value for y.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
years <- c(2012,2013,2014,2015)
count <- c(20,25,28,31)
spend <- c(300,320,310,341)
prop <- c(.7,.3,.5,.8)

df <- data.frame(years,count,spend,prop)

ggplot(df,aes(x = years, y = count)) +
  geom_col()

ggplot(df,aes(x = years, y = spend)) +
  geom_col()

ggplot(df,aes(x = years, y = prop)) +
  geom_col()
```

This is a very simple version, my actual graphs are much more elaborate.
So far I've used a loop to generate multiple graphs, I've created a function which is then executed in a loop and I've done the simple copy/paste.
Is some other, more formal, way of doing this? Either with `dplyr` and `ggplot` or anything else?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `melt()` your data and `facet_wrap()` the plot?

```
library(reshape2)
df <-melt(df, id=c("years")) 

library(ggplot2)  
ggplot(df,aes(x = years, y =value)) +
  geom_col() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

Or, if you want different y-axis scales:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = years, y =value)) +
  geom_col() + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that was quick. The second one is exactly what I was looking for. I use `gather()` and `facet_wrap` so much, but didn't think to use it in that way.

Comment: Yes I think you can use `gather()` as well, but I'm more comfortable with `melt()` due many times I've used it.